# Performance issues with vert.x

Tags: rx-java2, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

When running the test using apache bench for a vert.x application, we are seeing that the response time increased as we increase the number of concurrent users.

```
D:\httpd-2.2.34-win64\Apache2\bin>ab -n 500 -c 1 -H "Authorization: 5" -H "Span_Id: 4" -H "Trace_Id: 1" -H "X-test-API-KEY: 6"  http://localhost:8443/product_catalog/products/legacy/001~001~5ZP/terms
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Finished 500 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8443

Document Path:          /product_catalog/products/legacy/001~001~5ZP/terms
Document Length:        319 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1
Time taken for tests:   12.366 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      295094 bytes
HTML transferred:       159500 bytes
Requests per second:    40.43 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       24.733 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       24.733 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          23.30 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   0.5      1       3
Processing:     5   24  83.9      8    1293
Waiting:        5   23  83.9      8    1293
Total:          6   24  83.9      9    1293

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%      9
  66%     11
  75%     13
  80%     15
  90%     29
  95%     57
  98%    238
  99%    332
 100%   1293 (longest request)

D:\httpd-2.2.34-win64\Apache2\bin>ab -n 500 -c 2 -H "Authorization: 5" -H "Span_Id: 4" -H "Trace_Id: 1" -H "X-test-API-KEY: 6"  http://localhost:8443/product_catalog/products/legacy/001~001~5ZP/terms
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Finished 500 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8443

Document Path:          /product_catalog/products/legacy/001~001~5ZP/terms
Document Length:        319 bytes

Concurrency Level:      2
Time taken for tests:   7.985 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      295151 bytes
HTML transferred:       159500 bytes
Requests per second:    62.61 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       31.941 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       15.971 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          36.10 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   0.6      1       9
Processing:     6   30  71.5     12     720
Waiting:        5   30  71.4     12     720
Total:          7   31  71.5     13     721

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     13
  66%     16
  75%     21
  80%     24
  90%     53
  95%    113
  98%    246
  99%    444
 100%    721 (longest request)

D:\httpd-2.2.34-win64\Apache2\bin>ab -n 500 -c 3 -H "Authorization: 5" -H "Span_Id: 4" -H "Trace_Id: 1" -H "X-test-API-KEY: 6"  http://localhost:8443/product_catalog/products/legacy/001~001~5ZP/terms
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Finished 500 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8443

Document Path:          /product_catalog/products/legacy/001~001~5ZP/terms
Document Length:        319 bytes

Concurrency Level:      3
Time taken for tests:   7.148 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      295335 bytes
HTML transferred:       159500 bytes
Requests per second:    69.95 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       42.888 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       14.296 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          40.35 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   0.6      1       5
Processing:     6   42  66.2     22     516
Waiting:        6   41  66.3     22     515
Total:          7   42  66.3     23     516

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     23
  66%     31
  75%     43
  80%     51
  90%     76
  95%    128
  98%    259
  99%    430
 100%    516 (longest request)

D:\httpd-2.2.34-win64\Apache2\bin>ab -n 500 -c 4 -H "Authorization: 5" -H "Span_Id: 4" -H "Trace_Id: 1" -H "X-test-API-KEY: 6"  http://localhost:8443/product_catalog/products/legacy/001~001~5ZP/terms
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking localhost (be patient)
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
Finished 500 requests


Server Software:
Server Hostname:        localhost
Server Port:            8443

Document Path:          /product_catalog/products/legacy/001~001~5ZP/terms
Document Length:        319 bytes

Concurrency Level:      4
Time taken for tests:   7.078 seconds
Complete requests:      500
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      295389 bytes
HTML transferred:       159500 bytes
Requests per second:    70.64 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       56.623 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       14.156 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          40.76 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    1   0.6      1       4
Processing:     8   55 112.8     22    1112
Waiting:        8   55 112.7     21    1111
Total:          9   56 112.8     22    1112

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     22
  66%     31
  75%     43
  80%     59
  90%    120
  95%    213
  98%    294
  99%    387
 100%   1112 (longest request)
```

Also when the test is running, if we hit the API from another console, we see that the response time increases for that as well.

We have used the following code:

Router code:

```
router.route().handler(LoggerHandler.create(LoggerFormat.SHORT));
router.route().handler(ResponseTimeHandler.create());
router.route().handler(CorsHandler.create("*")
                .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.GET)
                .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.POST)
                .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.PUT)
                .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.DELETE)
                .allowedMethod(io.vertx.core.http.HttpMethod.OPTIONS)
                .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method")
                .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
                .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
                .allowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers")
                .allowedHeader("Content-Type")
                .allowedHeader("Trace_Id")
                .allowedHeader("Span_Id")
                .allowedHeader("Authorization")
                .allowedHeader("X-test-API-KEY")
                .allowedHeader("Accept"));
router.get("/product_catalog/products/legacy/:id/terms").handler(this::getByProductCode);
```

Server Creation:

```
vertx
    .createHttpServer()
    .exceptionHandler(event -> {
        logger.error("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "global_exception_handler", event, new GPCEntry("global_exception", event.getMessage() != null ? event.getMessage() : "")));
    })
    .connectionHandler(handler -> {
        handler.exceptionHandler(event -> {
            logger.error("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "global_exception_connection_handler", event, new GPCEntry("global_exception", event.getMessage() != null ? event.getMessage() : "")));
        });

    })
    .websocketHandler(handler -> {
        handler.exceptionHandler(event -> {
            logger.error("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "global_exception_websocket_handler", event, new GPCEntry("global_exception", event.getMessage() != null ? event.getMessage() : "")));
        });
    })
    .requestHandler(handler -> {
        handler.exceptionHandler(event -> {
            logger.error("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "global_exception_request_handler", event, new GPCEntry("global_exception", event.getMessage() != null ? event.getMessage() : "")));
        });
    })
    .requestHandler(router)
    .listen(serverPort, result -> {
        if (result.succeeded()) {
            logger.info("{}",
                    new GPCLogEvent(className, "start", new GPCEntry<>("Server started at port", serverPort)));
        } else {
            logger.error("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "start", result.cause(),
                    new GPCEntry<>("Server failed to start at port", serverPort)));
        }
    });
```

Handler Method:

```
private void getByProductCode(RoutingContext routingContext) {
    LocalDateTime requestReceivedTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    ZonedDateTime nowUTC = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    JsonObject jsonObject = commonUtilities.populateJsonObject(routingContext.request().headers());
    jsonObject.put("requestReceivedTime", requestReceivedTime.format(commonUtilities.getDateTimeFormatter()));
    jsonObject.put("path_param_id", routingContext.pathParam("id"));
    jsonObject.put("TRACING_ID",UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    long timeTakenInGettingRequestVar = 0;
    if (jsonObject.getString("requestSentTime") != null) {
        ZonedDateTime requestSentTime = LocalDateTime.parse(jsonObject.getString("requestSentTime"), commonUtilities.getDateTimeFormatter()).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        timeTakenInGettingRequestVar = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(requestSentTime.toLocalDateTime(), nowUTC.toLocalDateTime());
    }
    final long timeTakenInGettingRequest = timeTakenInGettingRequestVar;
    vertx.eventBus().send(TermsVerticleGet.GET_BY_PRODUCT_CODE,
            jsonObject,
            result -> {
                if (result.succeeded()) {
                    routingContext.response()
                            .putHeader("content-type", jsonObject.getString("Accept"))
                            .putHeader("TRACING_ID", jsonObject.getString("TRACING_ID"))
                            .putHeader("TRACE_ID", jsonObject.getString("TRACE_ID"))
                            .putHeader("SPAN_ID", jsonObject.getString("SPAN_ID"))
                            .putHeader("responseSentTime", LocalDateTime.now().format(commonUtilities.getDateTimeFormatter()))
                            .putHeader("timeTakenInGettingRequest", Long.toString(timeTakenInGettingRequest))
                            .putHeader("requestReceivedTime", nowUTC.toLocalDateTime().format(commonUtilities.getDateTimeFormatter()))
                            .putHeader("requestSentTime", jsonObject.getString("requestSentTime") != null ? jsonObject.getString("requestSentTime") : "")
                            .setStatusCode(200)
                            .end(result.result().body().toString())

                    ;
                    logger.info("OUT");
                } else {
                    ReplyException cause = (ReplyException) result.cause();

                    routingContext.response()
                            .putHeader("content-type", jsonObject.getString("Accept"))
                            .putHeader("TRACING_ID", jsonObject.getString("TRACING_ID"))
                            .putHeader("TRACE_ID", jsonObject.getString("TRACE_ID"))
                            .putHeader("SPAN_ID", jsonObject.getString("SPAN_ID"))
                            .putHeader("responseSentTime", LocalDateTime.now().format(commonUtilities.getDateTimeFormatter()))
                            .putHeader("timeTakenInGettingRequest", Long.toString(timeTakenInGettingRequest))
                            .putHeader("requestReceivedTime", nowUTC.toLocalDateTime().format(commonUtilities.getDateTimeFormatter()))
                            .putHeader("requestSentTime", jsonObject.getString("requestSentTime") != null ? jsonObject.getString("requestSentTime") : "")
                            .setStatusCode(cause.failureCode())
                            .end(cause.getMessage());
                    logger.info("OUT");
                }
            });

}
```

Worker Verticle:

```
private void getByProductCode(Message<JsonObject> messageConsumer) {
        LocalDateTime requestReceivedTime_handler = LocalDateTime.now();
        ZonedDateTime nowUTC_handler = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        final String TRACING_ID = messageConsumer.body().getString("TRACING_ID");
        final String TRACE_ID = !commonUtilities.validateNullEmpty(messageConsumer.body().getString("Trace_Id")) ? UUID.randomUUID().toString() : messageConsumer.body().getString("Trace_Id");
        final String SPAN_ID = !commonUtilities.validateNullEmpty(messageConsumer.body().getString("Span_Id")) ? UUID.randomUUID().toString() : messageConsumer.body().getString("Span_Id");

        logger.info("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "getByProductCode", new GPCEntry<>("IN", System.currentTimeMillis()), new GPCEntry<>("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID), new GPCEntry<>("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID)));

        // Run the validation
        logger.info("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "getByProductCode", new GPCEntry<>("validateCommonRequestHeader", true), new GPCEntry<>("IN", System.currentTimeMillis()), new GPCEntry<>("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID), new GPCEntry<>("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID)));
        commonUtilities.validateCommonRequestHeader(messageConsumer.body());
        logger.info("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "getByProductCode", new GPCEntry<>("validateCommonRequestHeader", true), new GPCEntry<>("OUT", System.currentTimeMillis()), new GPCEntry<>("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID), new GPCEntry<>("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID)));

        // Product code - Mandatory
        messageConsumer.body().put("product_codes", messageConsumer.body().getString("path_param_id"));

        // Product code validation
        if (commonUtilities.validateNullEmpty(messageConsumer.body().getString("product_codes"))) {
            commonUtilities.checkProductIAORGLOGOPCTCode(messageConsumer.body(), TRACING_ID, TRACE_ID, SPAN_ID, false);
        } else {
            messageConsumer.body().getJsonArray("errors").add("id (path parameter) is  mandatory field");
        }
        // There are validation errors
        if (messageConsumer.body().getJsonArray("errors").size() > 0) {
            messageConsumer.body().put("error_message", "Validation errors");
            messageConsumer.body().put("developer_message", messageConsumer.body().getJsonArray("errors").toString());
            messageConsumer.body().put("error_code", "400");
            messageConsumer.body().put("more_information", "There are " + messageConsumer.body().getJsonArray("errors").size() + " validation errors");
            messageConsumer.fail(400, Json.encode(commonUtilities.errors(messageConsumer.body(), TRACING_ID, TRACE_ID, SPAN_ID)));
            logger.info("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "getByProductCode", new GPCEntry<>("OUT", System.currentTimeMillis()), new GPCEntry<>("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID), new GPCEntry<>("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TIME_TAKEN", ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(requestReceivedTime_handler, LocalDateTime.now()))));
            return;
        }
        Handler<AsyncResult<CreditCardTerms>> dataHandler = data -> {
            if (data.succeeded()) {
                logger.info("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "getByProductCode", new GPCEntry<>("Success", true), new GPCEntry<>("IN", System.currentTimeMillis()), new GPCEntry<>("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID), new GPCEntry<>("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID)));
                /*routingContext.response()
                        .putHeader("content-type", messageConsumer.body().getString("Accept"))
                        .putHeader("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID)
                        .putHeader("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID)
                        .putHeader("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID)
                        .putHeader("responseSentTime", ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime().format(commonUtilities.getDateTimeFormatter()))
                        .putHeader("timeTakenInGettingRequest", Long.toString(timeTakenInGettingRequest))
                        .putHeader("requestReceivedTime", nowUTC_handler.toLocalDateTime().format(commonUtilities.getDateTimeFormatter()))
                        .putHeader("requestSentTime", messageConsumer.body().getString("requestSentTime") != null ? messageConsumer.body().getString("requestSentTime") : "")
                        .setStatusCode(200)
                        .end(Json.encode(data.result()));
                 */
                messageConsumer.reply(Json.encode(data.result()));
                logger.info("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "getByProductCode", new GPCEntry<>("OUT", System.currentTimeMillis()), new GPCEntry<>("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID), new GPCEntry<>("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TIME_TAKEN", ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(requestReceivedTime_handler, LocalDateTime.now()))));
            } else {
                logger.info("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "getByProductCode", new GPCEntry<>("onError", true), new GPCEntry<>("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID), new GPCEntry<>("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID)));
                if (data.cause() instanceof NoDocumentFoundException) {
                    messageConsumer.body().put("error_message", "Issue while fetching the details of the product");
                    messageConsumer.body().put("developer_message", messageConsumer.body().getJsonArray("errors").add(commonUtilities.getStackTrace(data.cause())).toString());
                    messageConsumer.body().put("error_code", "404");
                    messageConsumer.body().put("more_information", "Issue while fetching the details of the product");
                    //commonUtilities.errors(routingContext, messageConsumer.body(), TRACING_ID, TRACE_ID, SPAN_ID);
                    messageConsumer.fail(404, Json.encode(commonUtilities.errors(messageConsumer.body(), TRACING_ID, TRACE_ID, SPAN_ID)));
                } else {
                    messageConsumer.body().put("error_message", "Internal Server Error: Issue while fetching the details of the product");
                    messageConsumer.body().put("developer_message", messageConsumer.body().getJsonArray("errors").add(commonUtilities.getStackTrace(data.cause())).toString());
                    messageConsumer.body().put("error_code", "500");
                    messageConsumer.body().put("more_information", "Internal Server Error: Issue while fetching the details of the product");
                    //commonUtilities.errors(routingContext, messageConsumer.body(), TRACING_ID, TRACE_ID, SPAN_ID);
                    messageConsumer.fail(500, Json.encode(commonUtilities.errors(messageConsumer.body(), TRACING_ID, TRACE_ID, SPAN_ID)));
                }
                logger.error("{}", new GPCLogEvent(className, "getByProductCode", data.cause(), new GPCEntry<>("OUT", System.currentTimeMillis()), new GPCEntry<>("TRACING_ID", TRACING_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TRACE_ID", TRACE_ID), new GPCEntry<>("SPAN_ID", SPAN_ID), new GPCEntry<>("TIME_TAKEN", ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(requestReceivedTime_handler, LocalDateTime.now()))));

            }
        };
        // Search based on product codes
        gpcFlowable.getByGPID(TRACING_ID,
                TRACE_ID,
                SPAN_ID,
                TermsConstant.DOCUMENT_KEY,
                gpcFlowable.getByProductCode(TRACING_ID, TRACE_ID, SPAN_ID, messageConsumer.body().getString("product_codes"),
                        TermsConstant.API_VERSION_V1), // Get the GPID for the given IA or ORG~LOGO~PCT code
                TermsConstant.API_VERSION_V1,
                CreditCardTerms.class)
                .subscribe(doc -> dataHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(doc)),
                        error -> dataHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(error)));
    }
```

Comment: How many instances of worker verticles have you deployed?

Comment: 20 instances of the verticle